# Python - summing and grouping through a list

Tags: python, sorting

I have a big list of numbers like so:

```
a = [133000, 126000, 123000, 108000, 96700, 96500, 93800, 
 93200, 92100, 90000, 88600, 87000, 84300, 82400, 80700,
 79900, 79000, 78800, 76100, 75000, 15300, 15200, 15100,
 8660, 8640, 8620, 8530, 2590, 2590, 2580, 2550, 2540, 2540, 
 2510, 2510, 1290, 1280, 1280, 1280, 1280, 951, 948, 948,
 947, 946, 945, 609, 602, 600, 599, 592, 592, 592, 591, 583]
```

What I want to do is cycle through this list one by one checking if a value is above a certain threshold (for example 40000). If it is above this threshold we put that value in a new list and forget about it. Otherwise we wait until the sum of the values is above the threshold and when it is we put the values in a list and then continue cycling. At the end, if the final values don't sum to the threshold we just add them to the last list.

If I'm not being clear consider the simple example, with the threshold being 15

```
[20, 10, 9, 8, 8, 7, 6, 2, 1]
```

The final list should look like this:

```
[[20], [10, 9], [8, 8], [7, 6, 2, 1]]
```

I'm really bad at maths and python and I'm at my wits end. I have some basic code I came up with but it doesn't really work:

```
def sortthislist(list):
    list = a
    newlist = []
    for i in range(len(list)):
        while sum(list[i]) >= 40000:
            newlist.append(list[i])
    return newlist
```

Any help at all would be greatly appreciated. Sorry for the long post.

Comment: What version of Python are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function below will accept your input list and some limit to check and then output the sorted list:

```
a = [20, 10, 9, 8, 8, 7, 6, 2, 1]

def func(a, lim):
    out = []
    temp = []
    for i in a:
        if i > lim:
            out.append([i])
        else:
            temp.append(i)
            if sum(temp) > lim:
                out.append(temp)
                temp = []
    return out

print(func(a, 15))
# [[20], [10, 9], [8, 8], [7, 6, 2, 1]]
```

With Python you can iterate over the list itself, rather than iterating over it's indices, as such you can see that I use `for i in a` rather than `for i in range(len(a))`.

Within the function `out` is the list that you want to return at the end; `temp` is a temporary list that is populated with numbers until the sum of `temp` exceeds your `lim` value, at which point this `temp` is then appended to `out` and replaced with an empty list.

Answer (score 0):

```
def group(L, threshold):
    answer = []
    start = 0
    sofar = L[0]
    for i,num in enumerate(L[1:],1):
        if sofar >= threshold:
            answer.append(L[start:i])
            sofar = L[i]
            start = i
        else:
            sofar += L[i]
    if i<len(L) and sofar>=threshold:
        answer.append(L[i:])
    return answer
```

Output:

```
In [4]: group([20, 10, 9, 8, 8, 7, 6, 2, 1], 15)
Out[4]: [[20], [10, 9], [8, 8], [7, 6, 2]]
```

Answer (score 0):

Hope this will help :)

```
vlist = [20, 10,3,9, 7,6,5,4]

thresold = 15

result = []
tmp = []
for v in vlist:
    if v > thresold:
        tmp.append(v)
        result.append(tmp)
        tmp = []
    elif sum(tmp) + v > thresold:
        tmp.append(v)
        result.append(tmp)
        tmp = []
    else:
        tmp.append(v)

if tmp != []:
    result.append(tmp)
```

Here what's the result :

```
[[20], [10, 3, 9], [7, 6, 5], [4]]
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's yet another way:

```
def group_by_sum(a, lim):
    out = []
    group = None
    for i in a:
        if group is None:
            group = []
            out.append(group)

        group.append(i)

        if sum(group) > lim:
            group = None
    return out

print(group_by_sum(a, 15))
```

Answer (score 0):

We already have plenty of working answers, but here are two other approaches.

We can use [itertools.groupby](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby) to collect such groups, given a stateful accumulator that understands the contents of the group. We end up with a set of (key,group) pairs, so some additional filtering gets us only the groups. Additionally since itertools provides iterators, we convert them to lists for printing.

```
from itertools import groupby

class Thresholder:
  def __init__(self, threshold):
    self.threshold=threshold
    self.sum=0
    self.group=0
  def __call__(self, value):
    if self.sum>self.threshold:
      self.sum=value
      self.group+=1
    else:
      self.sum+=value
    return self.group
print [list(g) for k,g in groupby([20, 10, 9, 8, 8, 7, 6, 2, 1], Thresholder(15))]
```

The operation can also be done as a single reduce call:

```
def accumulator(result, value):
  last=result[-1]
  if sum(last)>threshold:
    result.append([value])
  else:
    last.append(value)
  return result
threshold=15
print reduce(accumulator, [20, 10, 9, 8, 8, 7, 6, 2, 1], [[]])
```

This version scales poorly to many values due to the repeated call to sum(), and the global variable for the threshold is rather clumsy. Also, calling it for an empty list will still leave one empty group.

Edit: The question logic demands that values above the threshold get put in their own groups (not sharing with collected smaller values). I did not think of that while writing these versions, but the accepted answer by Ffisegydd handles it. There is no effective difference if the input data is sorted in descending order, as all the sample data appears to be.